# SPO - Set Document Library as Site's Homepage

Tags: sharepoint-online, homepage

I want users to automatically be directed to the Document Library when visiting a Sharepoint Site (sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx). These are Office 365 group sites being used primarily for file sharing/syncing.

Using a page that contains the document library web part does not suffice as the web part does not include all the file and folder functions.

If I use Pages > +New > Link and use the document library URL, the resulting link opens a download of the URL shortcut when set as the homepage.

I see no available SPO cmdlets or parameters of existing cmdlets that allow setting the home page similar to Set-SPOHomeSite. This cmdlet seems to only set the global home site for the tenant, not for a specific site, and if I try to use Connect-SPOService on a specific /sites/ it fails to authenticate. I was hoping for something like:

`Set-SPOSite -Identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename -HomePageURL https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

You could use pnp powershell **Set-PnPHomePage** to set Document Library as Site's Homepage.

```
Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/
Set-PnPHomePage -RootFolderRelativeUrl Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

Please read this articel about Set-PnPHomePage:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnphomepage?view=sharepoint-ps